# Perform Macro on Close Event IF File was Saved

Tags: vba, ms-project

I want to run a macro "ExportToExcel" automatically when I close my .mpp file, BUT only if the Project was saved.

Reason: we only save this after we make changes; however, we are constantly opening the files to review. If this ran every time we closed, it would not be efficient.

I toyed with projectaftersave and could not make it work. I can make the following code work, but it runs EVERY time I close the file.

Sub Auto_Close()

Call ExportToExcel

End Sub

Expectations are to run my code when I close the .mpp ONLY if it was saved (not 'Save As') prior to closing.

Answer (score 1):

Try the before_save event in the "ThisProject" project objects ( [Microsoft Help Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa204873(v=office.11)) )

Something along the lines of:

```vb
    Option Explicit
    Private Sub Project_BeforeClose(ByVal pj As Project)
        ~~  Your code for doing things in excel ~~
    End Sub
```